# Excel Formula to define a Path

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hello , i want to define with Excel equation a destination(for example) for each path like i have in the picture below .

If Excel found in the column B that it is about the folder : **SourceFolder** , it will copy cells from D1 and add the file,
else if it find the folder: Destination , it will copy the cell D2

I do not know how to define that with excel . 
Can you help me with this please ?

the purpose of this is the save it at the end.  so i can do a macro to remove from the source to destination .
[image: Example]

Comment: It would probably be easier to do that using VBA rather than as a formula.  Does it **need** to be a formula?

Comment: I should do it in formula

Comment: Will the words you are searching for in column B always be "SourceFolder" and "Destination"?

Comment: Look at `Indirect()`.

Comment: I think indirect would be how you will wind up using the path.  It appears JeanLo wants to create the path.  As such this is string manipulation.

Comment: @ForwardEd yes ! it is a string manipulation ! i know it should be fone by FIND and IF formulas in excel but i do not know how .

Comment: @YowE3K i can have 3 sources and 3 destinations . Maybe it is about a function that once it didn t find the SourceFolder it will pass to destination ... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("\SOURCEFOLDER\",UPPER(B4)),0)>0,$D$1&TRIM(MID(B4,FIND("\SOURCEFOLDER\",UPPER(B4))+13,9999)),$D$2&TRIM(MID(B4,FIND("\DESTINATION\",UPPER(B4))+12,9999)))
```

The above formula will first test to see if "\SOURCEFOLDER\" exists in the source string.  (I used uppercase to ensure matching even if the user doesn't use the correct case.)  That is `IFERROR(FIND("\SOURCEFOLDER\",UPPER(B4)),0)>0`.

If "\SOURCEFOLDER\" **exists**, it grabs everything after the 13th character from the start of "\SOURCEFOLDER\" (i.e. from the last "\" onwards) and appends it to $D$1.  That is `$D$1&TRIM(MID(B4,FIND("\SOURCEFOLDER\",UPPER(B4))+13,9999))`.

If "\SOURCEFOLDER\" **doesn't exist**, I assume that it must contain "\DESTINATION\", so the last part grabs everything after the 12th character from the start of "\DESTINATION\" and appends it to $D$2.  That is `$D$2&TRIM(MID(B4,FIND("\DESTINATION\",UPPER(B4))+12,9999))`.

Comment: Talk us through that :)

Comment: @GaryEvans - I tried to add some explanations, but I never know how simple or how detailed to get.  Let me know if I need more explanation, and I will break each of the three portions down into yet more detail.

Comment: I'm not sure.  That formula should work if pasted into, say, cell C4 where your OP shows an "=".  I expected that you would then copy to other cells in column C as necessary.  But even if you pasted it somewhere else, as long as cell B4 contained either the word "\SOURCEFOLDER\" or "\DESTINATION\", it should have given a valid result.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `shows this string as false : "\SOURCEFOLDER\"`.

Comment: the problem was the "," it should be ";" and it works ! Thank you so much

Comment: I'm now absolutely confused, as I can't see any reason why a "," in that formula should be a ";" instead.  But I guess all that matters is that it works for you now.

Comment: @YowE3K how can we define that if destination  is empty it will not do anything and it leave the case empty please?

Comment: @JeanLo - to only use $D$2 if it is non-blank replace `$D$2&TRIM(MID(B4,FIND("\DESTINATION\",UPPER(B4))+12,9999))` with `IF($D$2="","",$D$2&TRIM(MID(B4,FIND("\DESTINATION\",UPPER(B4))+12,9999)))`